# Do I need to upgrade our hosting plan if I just use it for domain but hosting the files on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, hosting

The current setup was the application is load-balanced at AWS. The domain([www.Example.com](http://www.Example.com)) we are using is registered at GoDaddy.com.

My concern is that, do we need to upgrade our GoDaddy hosting even if the files are load-balance at AWS?

Let's say that we have had a 50K concurrent users.

Thanks for the insight in-advanced.

Comment: Upgrade from what to what? Sadly your question is not clear.

Comment: our godaddy hosting plan to a higher one. current we are using deluxe linux plan

Comment: @MarvinAbante No... No... You don't need to upgrade your hosting plan at Godaddy, you only use them as domain registrar, right? There is no point to upgrade your hosting plan. If you need more resources, then you need to upgrade your AWS plan since your domain host with AWS.

Comment: @MarkSpencer thanks for your generous suggestion. I'll keep that on mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "the application is load-balanced at AWS", it suggests that there is the following setup on AWS:

- One or more **Amazon EC2 instances** running a web application, and
- An **Elastic Load Balancer** that is directing incoming traffic to those instances

Your GoDaddy account *probably* has a **Domain Name** with a `CNAME` record that points to the DNS Name of the Load Balancer on AWS.

If this is true, then **you do not need a "hosting plan" on GoDaddy**, since it would just be managing your Domain Name. Scaling is not necessary for Domain Names.

Increasing the load would possibly require creating additional EC2 instances on AWS, but you might have an Auto Scaling group doing this for you automatically.

You should investigate what you actually have on GoDaddy and on AWS.

Comment: You removed my confusions... the setup your suggested is the actual setup we had and since we got no problem yet, it just suddenly came into my mind about that situation. Thank you for the clarifications...